# What is the purpose of Vector3.Clamp?

Tags: c#, math, vector

Both the [XNA `Vector3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195262.aspx) structure and the newer [System.Numerics `Vector3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector3.clamp(v=vs.111).aspx) provide a `Clamp()` method to "clamp" a vector between two other vectors.

...What does that even mean?  What practical purpose does this have?

Comment: Limits vector to min and max values (one vector is min other is max). It's a shortcut to writing min & max yourself. You could use this to for example clamp 3D cursor position not to go out of the bounds of the playing area.

Comment: Don't interpret min and max as vector but as bounds.  Clamping is an [established graphics term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)), distinct from clipping.  Not terribly practical but you do get the SIMD acceleration for free.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm aware of clamping scalars but I've never heard it applied to vectors.  I guess it makes sense if you think of it in terms of _"clamp each component individually,"_ but I'm struggling to see how that could actually be useful.  Meanwhile, clamping the magnitude _(an extremely common operation)_ is missing from both APIs...

Comment: Well, keep the ball inside the cube.  Don't confuse it for a general purpose vector type.  You only get the operations that are easy to accelerate, you have to bring the expensive ones yourself.